# limitations of .aspx web pages rendered in OS X Safari

Tags: safari

Specifically,

The goal is to understand the degree of compatibility of Safari with .aspx services.  Is there a comprehensive list of .aspx functionality that fails in Safari? OR

Is there a method \ line of thought to evaluate an .aspx page to determine any functional limits from a Safari perspective?

Although one can simply try the pages in Safari, I am reluctant to try it with this government website:

https://ritx-fl-sut.bswa.net/

State of Florida Department of Revenue website for reporting sales tax. The website allows me to login with Safari, but indicates:

> This website is optimized for use on a PC using Microsoft Internet
>   Explorer. If you are using any other web browsers, this site may not
>   appear or function as designed. We do not officially support the
>   Macintosh platform.

Comment: Is that really a government webpage its on a .net domain and your question reads like spam or some other nasty action

Comment: I believe it actually is a government webpage, although it's remarkably fraudulent looking.

Comment: In addition to the requirements for how to ask for off-site resources, be sure to remove all but one central question. Asking multiple distinct questions also is reason to put a hold on this question.

Comment: The webpage redirects to floridareveune.com and is legit.  They also say they support Safari:  http://floridarevenue.com/Pages/browser.aspx   What is the problem you're having, exactly?

Comment: Answer to your question: There's no .aspx-specific functionality that fails in Safari. The reason for this is that .aspx is entirely run on the server, not in the browser. The _output_ from that .aspx-page usually contains HTML5 and JavaScript that is used by the browser. Any incompatibility with Safari are then HTML or JavaScript incompatibilities, and thus not specific to .aspx. To sum it up, there's nothing "special" about browsing .aspx pages on Safari compared to browsing any other kind of page such as those generated by PHP, Java, Node.JS or indeed plain HTML.

Comment: @EzekielElin Most government pages do. They pay someone $50,000 to create a website. The person who creates it is an awful web designer and coder who makes it looks like its from the late 1990s.

Comment: @EzekielElin Proof? "This website is optimized for use on a PC using Microsoft Internet Explorer". I mean what modern day coder makes it for IE? Also "Macintosh". Who says "Macintosh" anymore?

Comment: @JBis-  Governments have a very difficult process to go through when it comes to website (re)design.  The firm/technology they selected years ago may have pitched a .NET/ASP solution and developed around an IE interface.  To bring it to modern standards likely requires a bid process which can take years to go from concept to product.  IE has basically been dead since Win10, so if they still require it, it tells you what a disaster FL's dev cycle is.

Comment: @JBis not sure why you're mentioning me, but regardless: Those have no relation to the fact the page is "ASPX."

Comment: @Allan Yes, that is true. But I feel like they could get someone to redesign/upgrade for cheap. And it would be worth it. I guess others disagree.

Comment: @JBis - What you *feel* they can do and what they *actually* can do as a matter of law are two separate things.  For the record, FL (state) law requires anything over $5000 to get a minimum of 3 bids.  Over another amount it has to go to RFP and that's assuming the legislature approved CapEx budget for it.  It has exactly zero do do with disagreeing about what's cheap/worth it.

Comment: @Allan I think we’re getting a bit off topic here. All I’m going to say is that I think if enough people saw enough value in a redesign then it would be accomplished.

Answer (score 3):

## ASPX is a Server Side Choice

[ASPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) is a server side technology. The web pages created by ASPX are not inherently limited on Safari browsers.

This is the same for other server side technologies such as Java, `php`, and `perl`.

### Developer's Responsibility

The developer of the `.aspx` created page is responsible for producing content that conforms to widely accepted web standards. These standards include [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5) and those published by the [World Wide Web Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium).

Web developers can refer to resources such as [QuirksMode](https://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) for a guide to what features are supported by which browsers.

### Webmasters' Stack Exchange

For help with specific web technologies and choices, please ask on the specialised [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, I would say there is no generalization you can apply since the .aspx just is the default extension for a specific web framework that runs on the server side. Think of .aspx as the container and not the content of the web page or the languages used.

As an analogy - you could ask if this container has a specific food in it:

[image]

Everyone might expect that it’s an Americanized version of fast food that vaguely resembles some street food from China, but it could be anything inside that container and not even food (or standard food for sure).

With JavaScript and some plug in - you could have binary data and not even HTML/CSS being delivered from that site or it could be amazingly standards-compliant and responsive web design.

Note, I haven’t even begun to mention Safari. Other than empirically testing each specific site you want and recording how it functions you’d need to analyze what you feel “compatible” means and then narrow your search for frameworks or tools.

If you wanted a fairly cross-platform web standards, you could do far worse than starting with http://validator.w3.org/

That tool throws 20 errors and 9 warnings against your site but that doesn’t mean Safari can’t do some or all of what it needs.

Comment: So it is not the .aspx container, but the contents that one should focus upon to understanding compatibility?